# BitBucket/Git error: You can only push your own commits in this repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

## Problem

I'm cannot push to a remote branch of a BitBucket repository, getting below error.

```
remote: You can only push your own commits in this repository
remote: Commit 0123456789abcdef was committed by my_username<my_email@company.com>
To ssh://git@bitbucket:7999/my_project/my_repo.git
! [remote rejected] my_branch -> my_branch (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@bitbucket:7999/my_project/my_repo.git'
```

## Observations

- It's probably the BitBucket [Verify Commit hook](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/validation-username-in-commits/qaq-p/723970) causing this
- I understand the above hook checks that the user doing the push must equal to the author of the new commits
- I ensured that `git config` has the correct email and username

## Questions

1. What exactly is being checked? Is it username and email? Is anything else checked?
2. How do I know which exact username and email combination BitBucket is expecting?

---

*[Error in git: You can only push your own commits in this repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52886362/error-in-git-you-can-only-push-your-own-commits-in-this-repository) asked the same question, where one solution was to disable the Verify Commit hook. However, that's just a workaround, and I do intend to have the hook continue running.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. What exactly is being checked?

Username and email. These are `user.name` and `user.email` in your Git configuration.

---

#### 2. Which username/email is BitBucket expecting?

Log into your BitBucket account. The expected values are listed under "Account settings".

---

[image]